# I am trying to compare two arrays inside For Loops

Tags: java, oop, for-loop

I am creating a Lottery Program where I want to compare the winning numbers with the players numbers and if any numbers match, they win a prize. I have used count to do this in my match() method but it comes up with an error when I try to compare two arrays - getWinningNumbers() and getNumbers() which are from the other classes PLAYER and WINNINGNUMBERS. The error I am getting is "actual and formal parameters differ in length" but I am unsure how to fix this. I am using linked lists for the first time as well. Any help would be much appreciated.

The piece of code I am having trouble with is in the method match() in the Lottery Class.

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
public void matches() {
        PLAYER currentPlayer = pHead;
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<6; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j< 6; j++) {
                if (win.getWinningNumbers(i) == currentPlayer.getNumbers(j)) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Don't use `==`.  That compares reference equality, and not whether the arrays contain the same values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following snippet in `matches()`:

```
if (win.getWinningNumbers(i) == currentPlayer.getNumbers(j)) {
                count++;
            }
```

To

```
if (win.getWinningNumbers()[i] == currentPlayer.getNumbers()[j]) {
                count++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example can help you a bit:

```
List<Integer> winningNumber = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(3, 9, 15, 1, 11, 18));
List<Integer> playerNumbers = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(2, 8, 15, 7, 11, 9));

matches(winningNumber, playerNumbers);

private static void matches(List<Integer> winningNumbers, List<Integer> playerNumbers) {
    if(winningNumbers.size() != playerNumbers.size()) {
        System.out.println("winning numbers and player numbers differ in size");
    }
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < winningNumbers.size(); i++) {
        if(winningNumbers.get(i) == playerNumbers.get(i)) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of matches in position: " + counter);

    // if the position of match is not important
    long matches = winningNumbers.stream()
            .filter(playerNumbers::contains)
            .count();
    System.out.println("Number of matches: " + matches);
}
```

> Number of matches in position: 2
>
> Number of matches: 3